# My onCreate funciton in Functions of firebase is not creating my desired collection in the cloud database

Tags: node.js, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I just typed a code in my index.js file of functions (firebase CLI).According to my code there must be a timeline collection created in cloud database of firebase.Function is healthy and there are no errors it gets deployed and even in the logs everything works fine. But still timeline collection is not created in the cloud databaese when I follow a user in my app.

this is my code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.onCreateFollower = functions.firestore
  .document("/followers/{userId}/userFollowers/{followerId}")
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    console.log("Follower Created", snapshot.id);
    const userId = context.params.userId;
    const followerId = context.params.followerId;

    // 1) Create followed users posts ref
    const followedUserPostsRef = admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("posts")
      .doc(userId)
      .collection("userPosts");

    // 2) Create following user's timeline ref
    const timelinePostsRef = admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("timeline")
      .doc(followerId)
      .collection("timelinePosts");

    // 3) Get followed users posts
    const querySnapshot = await followedUserPostsRef.get();

    // 4) Add each user post to following user's timeline
     querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        const postId = doc.id;
        const postData = doc.data();
        return timelinePostsRef.doc(postId).set(postData);
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to execute a variable number of asynchronous calls in parallel, you should use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), in order to wait that all these different asynchronous calls are completed before indicating to the CF platform that it can cleanup the CF. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions for more details.

```
exports.onCreateFollower = functions.firestore
  .document("/followers/{userId}/userFollowers/{followerId}")
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    
    const userId = context.params.userId;
    const followerId = context.params.followerId;

    // ...

    // 3) Get followed users posts
    const querySnapshot = await followedUserPostsRef.get();

    // 4) Add each user post to following user's timeline
     const promises = [];
     querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        //query results contain only existing documents, the exists property will always be true and data() will never return 'undefined'.
        const postId = doc.id;
        const postData = doc.data();
        promises.push(timelinePostsRef.doc(postId).set(postData));
    });

    return Promise.all(promises);

  });
```

Comment: Even after using this Promise.all() approach, the problem still exists.It is not creating the collection in the database.

Comment: I have tested my code and confirm it does work. Do you see any error in the Cloud Functions console?

Comment: sorry sir it was my mistake, I just deployed my function again and now your code is working. It is all set. Thank you for your help.